# How use Django with Tornado web server?

Tags: ajax, django, webserver, comet, tornado

How do I use Django with the Tornado web server?

Answer (score 46):

it's very simple ( especially with django 1.4) .

1 - just build your django project( and apps ) and make sure it works fine.

2- create a new python file at the root folder ( same dir where you used `django-admin.py startproject`)

3- then copy the code below , edit the `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` line, and paste it in that new .py file.

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.wsgi
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#sys.path.append('/home/lawgon/') # path to your project ( if you have it in another dir).


def main():
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myProject.settings' # path to your settings module
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
    container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(application)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(container)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Django 1.6+ it should be like this:

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

def main():
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings' # path to your settings module
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(application)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(container)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Bravo! I am really looking forward to try that!

Comment: How to call the new.py file

Comment: Doubt: this, of course, won't make Django magically asynchronous, and Python is not such a great multithreading language. So, this server won't support serving multiple concurrent requests, am I right?

Comment: Note that this wont serve the static files.

Comment: @AlanFranzoni Tornado is more than just async. The point is it is a much faster & lighter weight thing to get up and running than Apache or Nginx and way way easier to manage.

Comment: @uchuugaka of course it's lighter.. it's single threaded! Define 'faster', though... it may be faster at starting up and serving a SINGLE request, but will choke with more than one concurrent request! http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html - by the way, my opinion was not on Tornado vs Django, it was on Django WITH Tornado.

Comment: What does the tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start() mean?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:**

I created a minimal working demo which shows how to use the Tornado web server to run nicely with django:

https://github.com/tamasgal/django-tornado

**ORIGINAL POST:**

Just a remark: The WSGI application workflow has been changed from 1.6 to 1.7. You have to replace the import

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

with

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

and change the application initialisation from

```
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

to

```
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**This is the modified code from the Moayyad Yaghi's answer:**

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.wsgi
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#sys.path.append('/home/lawgon/') # path to your project ( if you have it in another dir).


def main():
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myProject.settings' # path to your settings module
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(application)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(container)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a project called [tornado-proxy](https://github.com/senko/tornado-proxy) that would help you. But I would like to recommend that you use [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org). In the Nginx config you could now use proxy_pass to direct your calls like this:

```
location /comet {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}

location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Comment: Django is not a web server. It comes with a basic web server to aid in developing Django projects, but which is not suitable to be used in production environments.

Comment: Completely right, though I assumed that xRobot was using Django (with it's webserver) as a complete webserver/framework for building his web project. I spared him the details.

Comment: I have played with chat and tornado on my computer and it works perfectly. 
On my server I am using nginx and django framework but I don't know where to put Tornado.
P.s. Have you tried also the Push Module for Nginx ?
Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry, I have not. But what do you mean with "put Tornado"? I have my Tornado source in a subfolder for my project and then I start it with:  
sudo nginx -c conf/nginx.conf

Comment: ah ok... I will insert Tornado source in a subfolder.
Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2):

In real world you would connect Django and some production-ready webserver with [WSGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/). This demo shows how you can run Tornado (and it's webserver) and Django side by side from one python module serving different URL prefixes: https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo.
Tornado would block on serving any request directed to Django, though.