# Couldn't run Tornado server in windows

Tags: python, django, tornado

Am trying to integrate Django app with Tornado for some asynchronous request handling (chat). (Reference - https://github.com/thejsj/django-and-rethinkdb)

For that reason, I integrated but couldn't run the tornado_main.py after initiating the Django app in windows (command prompt as admin).

when I run

```
>c:\python27\python tornado_main.py
```

It throws below error

[image]

I tried changing different django versions and tried the code as suggested in [How use Django with Tornado web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534603/how-use-django-with-tornado-web-server)

Am not sure what is wrong with the configurations that were missing.

Here is my **tornado_main.py** code-

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.conf import settings
import os
from tornado.options import options, define, parse_command_line
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.gen
from change_feed import print_changes, SocketHandler, MessageHandler

django.setup()

def main():
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
  wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
  )
  current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  static_folder = os.path.join(current_dir, 'static')
  tornado_app = tornado.web.Application([
    ('/new-messages/', SocketHandler),
    ('/messages/', MessageHandler),
    (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, { 'path': static_folder }),
    ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
  ])
  server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
  server.listen(8000)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(print_changes)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Am using django 1.8.1
Python 3.4

Could you please suggest how to run this server on windows ?

Here is **Settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=1gnq3++4*3to$cun@-(f86j_4f^!-k96#f%eej3k$be1o^17o'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testTornado.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testTornado.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'tornadotest',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'dhyana007',      
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGGING_CONFIG=None
```

Comment: What in your settings.py? Have you tried set `LOGGING_CONFIG=None`?

Comment: Hi @Ingaz, I just tried adding LOGGING_CONFIG=None. It gives same error. Could you kindly check the edit?

Comment: I think you're missing: `sys.path.append('/home/lawgon/') # path to your project` before setting `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings' #name of your application`.

Comment: Before adding this.. I tried differently, it now throws No Module name 'app' :(

Comment: app is my django (INSTALLED_APPS).. When I remove it, tornado doesn't throw any error.. but I cant run my django app :(

Comment: Of course. What is the name of your app? After `sys.path.append` it must be `import`-able: as `import your_app` and `import your_app.settings`

Comment: app name is 'app' itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98486/discussion-between-ingaz-and-sathish).